# Why is the Telerik RadGrid KeyValues string empty when UpdateCommand is running?

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

While debugging the RadGrid1_UpdateCommand I noticed that the KeyValues of the GridEditableItem are empty (just a set a brackets).  There are 49 SavedOldValues.  The data table that sources the grid has a primary key on it.
The grids data source is manually specified in the C# code.

Why would the KeyValues be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified the key name(s) for `DataKeyNames` attribute on MasterTableView element of the RadGrid? Say your PK column is called, ID, then you can just assign it like this.

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="radgrid1">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>...</Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Then you can get the key value via DataKeyValues collection and then convert it as an integer for use.

```
protected void radgrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var keyValue = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["ID"].ToString();
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(keyValue);
}
```